# Junit, java : Mocking a method

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have created a java class (A) that is calling a method from another class (B). The other class (B) is calling a method from third class (C). I have mocked a few methods from B class. I'm trying to mock a method from C class  . However, it is not working. The test class is like below:

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestA {

  private A a= new A();

  @Mock
  private B b;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    setInternalState(a, "b", b);
  }

  @Test
  public void testMethodA() throws Exception {          
    when(b.methodMock(anyString())).thenReturn(myValue);
    when(c.methodMockC(anyString()).thenReturn(myvalue2);
    result=a.methodA("xyz");
    Assert.assertEquals("anyValue", result.getValue());
  }
}
```

Classes to be tested are as below.

```
public class A
{
  public B b=new B();

  public String methodA (String value) {      
    String myValue=b.methodMock(value);            
    String result=b.methodB(myValue,value)
    return result;
  }
}

public class B
{
  public C c=new C();
  public String methodB (String myValue,String value) {
    String result=c.methodC(myValue);
    return result;
  }   

  public String methodMock (String value) {
    return result;
  }   
}

public class C
{
  public String methodC (String myValue) {
    result=methodMockC(myValue);
    return result;
  }   

  public methodMockC(String val){
    return value;
  }
}
```

My method b.methodMock is working fine but c.methodMockC is not working (2nd level mock). Would really appreciate a response. Thanks in advance.

Edit: I need to mock methodMockC in Class C that is getting called as methodB->methodC->mockMethodC via injected object b .

Comment: in TestA , c.methodMockC(anyString()) ----> where is c defined

Comment: You tell me, @Utkarsh Gupta have used when(c.methodMockC(anyString()).thenReturn(myvalue2); in TestA class

Comment: There do you inject the mock `c` into `b`?

Comment: Please refer to my reply @ItayMaman...thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Several things:

- The code, as posted, does not compile. In class `C`, you have the `methodMockC()` method. It returns the `value` variable but this variable is not defined. Similarly the `result` variable used in `methodC()` is also not defined.
- In class `C` you have a field of type named `c` that is initialized with `new C()`. This means that whenever you're creating an instance of `C` the code will try to initialize the field which entails the creation of a second `C` instance. This instance also has a `c` field so it will entail the creation of a third `C` instance, which in turn will entail the creation of a *fourth* `C` instance which in turn...; See my point? when a `C` object is created you actually run into an infinite loop.
- In order to use the mocked `B` object your test creates, you have to somehow inject it into the `a` object. Is this what `setInternalState()` is doing? Specifically, does it is do something like `a.b = b` ? If it does not your `a` object will not use your `B` mock.
- There is no need to mock the `C` class. If your `a` object is using mock `B` object then it no longer invokes method of the original `B` class and thus there is no need to mock `C` - a will only invoke methods on your mock `B` and the behavior of this method is specified by your test (in the `when(b.??????).thenReturn(????)` lines).

Comment: @ItayMaman...1) I know it doesn't compile..it is just a sample and not a good one at that, i admit :(
2)That was an error on my part.. C c =new C() ...in Class C..removed it.
3)Yes ..i am using setInternalState() for injecting mock object.
4)Normally yes.. if that method is present in the mocked method but...i have mocked b.methodMock(no use ..just for representation) but i want to mock methodMockC that is getting called from methodB via call c.methodC.......!!

Comment: @utkarshgupta when you mock an object all  methods of the object are mocked out not just the ones on which you called `when(....);` you can see that by doing this experiment: change the impl. of all methods of `C` to `throw new RuntimeException();` and run the test. this will have no effect on the test because the mocked `C` is never used once `B` has been mocked.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mock **private** method with mockito. Change you private method(you wrote wrong) from class C

```
  private methodMockC(String val){
      return value;
  }
```

to **public**

```
  public String methodMockC(String val){
      return value;
  }
```

Comment: @SaiYeYanNaingAye.....yup...sorry..typo..edited it...also do see my reply to ItayMaman...it may help to understand my issue a bit better...thanks..:)